# Colorize a greyscale texture in OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, colors, mask, brush

I would like to use a texture similar to a Photoshop style brush (example: http://designblurb.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/grungy-watercolor-brushes.jpg), and allow the user to choose a color for it, so when it is drawn to the screen the grey's black's become colorized by the user's selection.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this? Are there texture environment variables that can do this?

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it just comes down to combining the texture's color with some constant color. So you have greyscale texture (be it either a `GL_RGB` texture with all components of a color having the same value, or just a `GL_LUMINANCE` texture). The actual combination of both colors depends on your OpenGL ES version.

In ES 1 you just use the `GL_MODULATE` texture environment to multiply the texture color with the object's/vertex' color (either computed by lighting or set by `glColor` or `glColorPointer` if lighting is disabled, which seems your case):

```
glColor(...);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
//draw a textured object
```

In ES 2 you of course have to do it yourself in the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec4 color;

varying vec2 texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(tex, texCoord).r;
}
```

If all these things don't tell you anything (depending on your version), then you should probably delve a bit depper into the basics of OpenGL ES and combining a texture with a constant color is your least problem.

Comment: Ah hah, I do see it taking effect now, however it seems that since the texture is mainly black, the color is not taking much effect. I wonder if there is a different Environment variable or blend function that can create a stronger color, or should I lighten the brush greyscale mask?

Comment: @TomPennetta Well, of course the color is where the brush is white. If your brush represents black as color (which you images somehow suggest), you need to switch colors. And you should also lighten it up if you want it brighter. The exact color is only given by the completely white parts, everything else can only be darker. You may experiment with alpha blending to get additive effects (parts brighter when painted by the brush more than one time), but I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: Understood, I am used to Photoshop where the darker the brush is the stronger the color. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @TomPennetta Since colors are multiplied, 1 (white) times a color gives the color and 0 (black) times a color gives black.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. It seems to be working the way it was intended now.